# Calling methods with same signature dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class SomeClass
{

public void ActionFunction()
{
}

public void Do1(int num) {...}

public void Do2(int num) {...}

etc.
}
```

In `ActionFunction` I want to read in strings and then call any of the Do's (`Do1`, `Do2`, etc.). Since all the functions have the same signature I was thinking this was a job for Delegates. But you can't pass in the string name of a function to delegates, and I'm trying to avoid having a giant switch to figure out which one to call.

I realize I can use reflection for this, but am trying to avoid this due to the performance reasons.

Comment: I need ActionFunction to take in a file of commands to run, with the commands being Do1, Do2, etc. The sequence and set of actions can change depending on the user. It's hard to go into more detail without writing too much, but that's basically what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always maintain a dictionary, internally, and call based on that.  You could even use reflection to load the dictionary values, since this would be a one-time, up front cost, and calling would be quick.

```
private Dictionary<string, Action<int>> doMethods = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>();
public SomeClass()
{
    Type t = typeof(SomeClass);
    var methods = t.GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("Do"));

    foreach(var method in methods)
         doMethods.Add(method.Name, (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), this, method, true));
}

public void ActionFunction(string name, int num)
{
    this.doMethods[name](num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a dictionary of `<string, Func<int>>` where the key is the string and the value is a delegate of the method to call.  Then you do something like `dict["string"].Value.Invoke()`

Comment: That would be my suggestion too, except that `Func<int, void>` is not legal - use `Action<int>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 4.0, the opensource framework [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface) can use the dlr to call your actions based on a name [4x faster than reflection](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_Impromptu.InvokeMemberAction%28object_target,_String_Or_In).

```
Impromptu.InvokeMemberAction(target, actionName, num);
```